# Please help to get the right symbol for my macros

Tags: macros

I am not good at macros, so please can someone assist me.  I need to have this symbol in my macro

> ŉ

So the comma is like a 9 not a 6
but the macro my colleague wrote for me does not work on my pc but it works on hers — this is it here:

```
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "'n "
        .Replacement.Text = "’n "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
```

Comment: In which way is this related to (La)TeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). However, as per @ Qrrbrbirlbel, I don't think that you question is (La)TeX related.  Just using `'n` should give you that symbol, but not sure if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: You might be interested in `\textquoteright n` or just plain ol' `'n`.

Comment: Googling for `Select.Find.Execute` I found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx(v=vs.80).aspx), so clearly this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three different symbols packaged as a macro that you might be looking for:

[image]

The last is one is from Werner's comment.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\Na}{'n}
\newcommand*{\Nb}{`n}
\newcommand*{\Nc}{\textquoteright n}


\begin{document}
\Na  \quad\verb|'n| 

\Nb  \quad\verb|`n| 

\Nc  \quad\verb|\textquoteright n|
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\Na` would be the right one. [ŉ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%89) is actually a Unicode character. Libertine, for example, has the glyph under the name `napostrophe` (and `uni0149`).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It is in Unicode, but its use is deprecated, [see here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf)